# Gson error occurs when I convert json to gson object Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, gson

I am getting following error when I convert json to gson :

E/AndroidRuntime(1142): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 51

I have json like this :

```
  {

"ResultCode": "0",
"ErrorMessage": null,
"Payload": [
    {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Wars"
            },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … },
            { … }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Items": [ … ]
    },
    {
        "Items": [ … ]
    }
]

}
```

I have two classes : MResult class

```
 import java.util.List;

 public class MResult{
private String ErrorMessage;   
private String ResultCode;
private List<List<Item>> Payload;

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return ErrorMessage;
}
public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
}
public String getResultCode() {
    return ResultCode;
}
public void setResultCode(String resultCode) {
    ResultCode = resultCode;
}
public List<List<Item>> getPayload() {
    return Payload;
}
public void setPayload(List<List<Item>> payload) {
    Payload = payload;
}

}
```

Item class :

```
 public class Item{

private String Title;

 public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

 }
```

I am getting the error on this line :

```
 MResult serviceResult = new Gson().fromJson(result,MResult.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another class to hold Items

```
List<Foo> Payload;

class Foo{
   List<Item> Items;
}
```